# MP3 Podcast Problems... mp3 file format?

Tags: audio, mp3

I'm having trouble with an audio file.

If you look over at this [Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60183/itunes-podcast-rejected-by-apple) I submitted, you'll see I was having issues with getting a podcast to work in iTunes. I finally narrowed it down (I think).  Everything seemed correct, but I finally tried a couple different MP3 files and submitted the podcast and it worked.

So, I'm wondering if the audio file my client gave me has issues.

When I go to "Get Info" for other MP3 files, it shows things like "Audio Channels", "Total Bit Rate", and stuff like that. The MP3 file I am using doesn't really show anything. All I know is it says it's "Kind: MP3 audio" and "64865838 bytes".

Any thoughts? I know pretty much nothing about audio, I'm a web developer lol. I can provide the audio file if anyone wants to download it and check it out. Thanks!

Comment: If one of the answers below successfully solved your problem, would you consider marking one of them "accepted"?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after a long period of troubleshooting, I determined it was the MP3 file that was having issues. After importing it into GarageBand and exporting it from there, it finally worked! I received the MP3 file from the client. He is a preacher and they recorded it at the church. Then he uploaded it to Google Drive and I downloaded it from there. It sounds like it was not encoded correctly, but I am not an audio expert.